# Android gson invalid ClassCastException

Tags: java, android, gson

**Hi I have a Json String as this**

```
   {"lines":[{"line":"COLOMBO - BADULLA"},{"line":"COLOMBO - MATALE"},{"line":"COLOMBO - PUTTLAM"},{"line":"COLOMBO - THANDIKULAM"},{"line":"COLOMBO - TALAIMANNAR"},{"line":"COLOMBO - BATTICALOA"},{"line":"COLOMBO - TRINCOMALEE"},{"line":"COLOMBO - MATARA"},{"line":"COLOMBO - AVISSAWELLA"},{"line":"COLOMBO - MIHINTALE"}]}
```

And Its Domain **Classes** as This

```
public class Line{
    private String line;

    public String getLine(){
        return this.line;
    }
    public void setLine(String line){
        this.line = line;
    }
}



public class Lines{
    private List lines;

    public List getLines(){
        return this.lines;
    }
    public void setLines(List lines){
        this.lines = lines;
    }
}
```

And Mapping **gson to objects** as this

*FYI : for jsonString i passes the String not the JSON URL* (using a HttpGet)

```
    Line ln =null;
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    ln = gson.fromJson(jsonString, Line.class); not the URL
    return ln;
```

The exception throws is :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.sab.loc/com.sab.loc.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sab.loc.Line cannot be cast to java.util.List
```

Im not sure what goes wrong as , i think that my class definitions are correct which i generated using http://jsongen.byingtondesign.com/

Any idea where does it does wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `jsonString` contained an `array` or `list` of objects assigned to `lines`.

`{"lines":[{"line":"COLOMBO - BADULLA"},...]}`

So the class you try to map this `jsonString` data to, must have a `lines` variable.

`Line.java` class does not have a `lines` variable.

Try this:

```
public class Lines {
    private List<Line> lines;

    public List<Line> getLines(){
        return this.lines;
    }
    public void setLines(List<Line> lines){
        this.lines = lines;
    }
}

public class Line {
    private String line;

    public String getLine(){
        return this.line;
    }
    public void setLine(String line){
        this.line = line;
    }
}
```

And this:

```
Lines ln = new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, Lines.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your json is not directly returning `Line class.` It's returning `Lines class.`
and you are trying to `cast it into Line` which is not a type of `List` that's way
it is `throwing class cast exception`.

you can define the field `private List lines;` inside your `Line.java class`.

better to defined `generic type private List<Lines> lines;` inside your `Line.java` class
and `generate the setter getter stubs of lines`.